# Regarding Python's tfidf and word-cloud

Tags: python, data-visualization, tf-idf, word-cloud

I recently was working with word-cloud and I saw that the words in the image are bigger or smaller with respect to their importance in the document.

TFIDF is somewhat similar to it.

But I could not understand underlying working philosophy of WordCloud how does it work, how does it calculate the importance of a word.

If we have wordCloud why do we need TFIDF and vice-versa

Also if we have calculated result from TFIDF how to visualize it.

Please help me I feel this things would be very helpful to build the foundation
Thank you in advance

Comment: You are probably overthinking it. You don't point out the exact implementation of "word cloud" that you are looking at, but most do not bother to verify the "importance" of a word, only their relative frequencies in the entire source text. Which is why they need a list to weed out common words – if not, "the" and "an" and "of" would be the largest words for almost all texts.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try to look into it with different perspective